# Can't use global variables in grafana

Tags: grafana

In grafana [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/global-variables/) there is information about global variables, but when i try using them in my query (I am using mysql database), they don't get translated. Why is that?

An example:

For query

```
SELECT
  '$__dashboard'
```

Gives in generated query:

```
SELECT
  '$__dashboard'
```

But when I do select on variable defined by myself in the editor it works just fine.

Comment: What is your Grafana version?

Comment: @JanGaraj I have: Enterprise (Free & unlicensed) v7.0.5 (from June 26 2020)